# how to change all div values on a page

Tags: jquery, html, download

i have three div's on a page with same ID's

```
<div id="downloaded">1200</div>
```

Now when i call the function downloadThis("filename","divID"); i want that the value of every div with id "Downloaded" should change, i am using jquery. Kindly help.

Comment: It is wrong to have the same id on more than one element.

Comment: Yep you should change it to <div class="downloaded">

Comment: Just to re-emphasis the point. An id is an identifier, which also means it has to be unique within the same DOM.

Answer (score 4):

It is not valid to have more than one element on the page with the same ID.

<strike>To set value you could use the [html](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/html#val) function:</strike>

```
$('#downloaded').html('new value');>
```

A more semantically correct way to achieve this is to assign the divs a class name and use a class selector:

```
<div class="downloaded">123</div>

$('.downloaded').html('new value');
```

Comment: Using IDs doesn't even work, as jQuery selects only the first element, assuming that there will be no more as IDs should be unique. So `$('#downloaded').html('new value')` only affects the first div only - using classes is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

```
function downloadThis(a, b) {
    $("#downloaded").text(b);
}
```

But as James Black mentioned, your ID elements should all be unique on a page. I would change it to be a class name like so:

```
<div class="downloaded">...</div>

function downloadThis(a, b) {
    $(".downloaded").text(b);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, Id's need to be unique. But what you want to achieve can be done by using the class attribute

```
$('.downloaded').toggleClass('.done')
```

Answer (score 0):

I would change the id to be unique, and perhaps you can put in either a common className or have downloaded_1, downloaded_2, downloaded_3 as the ids.

If you go with the latter solution then you can get the elements by:

```
var elems = $('div').filter(function() {
    return this.id.match(/downloaded/)})
```

Then you can use the html function to set them, or do whatever else you want.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i have assign different values to the DIV for example.

```
<div id="song1Downloads">1500</div>
```

Now this div is on 2 sides left and center. Infront of both is a download button clicking which following code is executed,

```
function downloadIt(file,divName){
  var i = parseInt($("#"+divName).text());
  var updated = i+1;
  //alert('#'+divName+'');
  $("#"+divName).html("<b><u>"+(updated)).hide().fadeIn("fast");
  setTimeout(function(){ $("#downloadBar").slideDown("fast") }, 700);
  setTimeout('tryToDownload("new.php?fileName='+file+'")', 400);
  setTimeout(function(){ $("#downloadBar").slideUp("fast") }, 5000);
}
```

But still it doesn't updates the DIV's only 1 div on the left side is updated!!